# Password-protected Wordpress page with sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a page on my wordpress site a password protected page. However, the page template for this specific page has a sidebar widget that does not get hidden along with the page. I need for the sidebar widget to appear with the page only after user has entered correct password to view the page.

Does anyone if this is possible?

Comment: More detail please. How did you do password protected page? If page protected, you cannot go that page. What is the widget name on sidebar? More detail needed in order to help

Answer (score 0):

You may have to make edits to your templates. See if link below helps:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-sidebar-content-if-page-is-password-protected